# Cannot access wiki after changing theme

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I was changing the themes of the ROS wiki and after testing one of them I cannot use the wiki:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
> error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
> administrator, [no address given] and
> inform them of the time the error
> occurred, and anything you might have
> done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
> be available in the server error log.
> Apache Server at wiki.ros.org Port 80

Now, in order to use the wiki I had to clear the browser cache and use it anonymously. Whenever I try to login this wild error appears.

Does anybody know how I can restart the preferences of my wiki account?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209546/cannot-access-wiki-after-changing-theme/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After logging in you might be able to go to: http://wiki.ros.org/?action=userprefs&sub=prefs to change your theme.

However if the theme is broken on that page too. I don't know how to manually override the theme.

Do you know what theme you tried? And what's your username?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-22**:
My username is JavierVGomez and the theme is `explorer`. I have checked the error with a test account and the same is happening. I also tried to access from cache but didn't work. If you can just reset the account that is OK, as I have done nothing with it yet. Otherwise, I will create a new one.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-22**:
I believe I've reverted your account to the rostheme. Please confirm.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-22**:
I've disabled the theme too: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/pull/131

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-22**:
Yep, it works now. Thank you!